# Make Airflow KubernetesPodOperator clear image cache without setting image_pull_policy on DAG?

Tags: celery, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I'm running Airflow on Google Composer. My tasks are KubernetesPodOperators, and by default for Composer, they run with the Celery Executor.

I have just updated the Docker image that one of the KubernetesPodOperator uses, but my changes aren't being reflected. I think the cause is that it is using a cached version of the image.

How do I clear the cache for the KubernetesPodOperator? I know that I can set `image_pull_policy=Always` in the DAG, but I want it to use cached images in the future, I just need it to refresh the cache now.

Here is how my KubernetesPodOperator (except for the commented line):

```
processor = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='processor',
        name='processor',
        arguments=[filename],
        namespace='default',
        pool='default_pool',
        image='gcr.io/proj/processor',
#       image_pull_policy='Always' # I want to avoid this so I don't have to update the DAG
    )
```

### Update - March 3, 2021

I still do not know how to make the worker nodes in Google Composer reload their images once while using the `:latest` tag on images (or using no tag, as the original question states).

I do believe that [@rsantiago's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266872/make-airflow-kubernetespodoperator-clear-image-cache-without-setting-image-pull?noredirect=1#comment114938484_64266872) would work, i.e. doing a rolling restart. A downside of this approach that I see is that, by default, in Composer worker nodes run in the same node pool as the Airflow infra itself. This means that doing a rolling restart would possibly affect the Airflow scheduling system, Web interface, etc. as well, although I haven't tried it so I'm not sure.

The solution that my team has implemented is adding version numbers to each image release, instead of using no tag, or the `:latest` tag. This ensures that you know exactly which image should be running.

Another thing that has helped is adding `core.logging_level=DEBUG` to the "Airflow Configuration Overrides" section of Composer. This will output the command that launched the docker image. If you're using version tags as suggested, this will display that tag.

I would like to note that setting up local debugging has helped tremendously. I am using PyCharm with the docker image as a "Remote Interpreter" which allows me to do step-by-step debugging inside the image to be confident before I push a new version.

Comment: Have you tried to perform a [rolling restart](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#starting_a_basic_rolling_update) of the instance group of the underlying GKE cluster? if you select _replace nodes_ in such operation  it is possible that the new Docker image should be reloaded without modifying the configuration in the operator.